# How to cast latitude, longitude coordinates as postgres geography type

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

My table has two float columns for latitude and longitude coordinates.

I want to use PostGIS's [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to find all records which are within a certain distance from a given point.

The signature of `ST_DWithin` expects the first two parameters to be geometry or geography datatypes so I'm pretty sure the solution is to cast the lat/lng coordinates as geography, but I can't get it to work.

Here's what *doesn't* work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stops 
WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-77.09 38.89)'),
                  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || stops.lng || ' ' || stops.lat || ')'), 10000.0)
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  function st_geogfromtext(unknown) does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM stops WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeogFromText('SRID=...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to remove the float columns and replace them with a [geography column](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography).

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the GIS SE community (http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Are you saying there is no possible way to cast the lat,lng floats as Geography?

Comment: @MartinValgur My question is entirely related to programming. The description of GIS reads `a question and answer site for cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals`. Can't see how how that's a better fit than S.O.

Comment: Yes, SO would be the right place to ask. Turns out, though, that the question way a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Woops.

Turns out the original syntax (above) was actually correct. But I missed a key step afer installing PostGIS:

`psql -d <DATABASE_NAME_HERE> -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis";`

Turns out you have to enable it on each database for it to work. *This* is why the function was unrecognized.

As there aren't many resources out there for this, I'm going to leave the question in case it proves useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

An example in Gilbert Le Blanc's [link](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) seems to contain a method for casting during a function call:

```
SELECT ST_Distance('LINESTRING(-122.33 47.606, 0.0 51.5)'::geography, 
    'POINT(-21.96 64.15)':: geography);
```

Can you adapt that to your use case?